# ¿Cómo usar OPENJSON con estructura compleja?

Tags: sql-server, json

Tengo el año e necesito que el salga en la conversión.

**1 - El código**

```
DECLARE @JSON AS VARCHAR(MAX) =
```

'{
"status": "SUCCESS",
"mes": [
{
"enero": "01",
"febrero": "02",
"marzo": "03"
}
],
"año": 2022
}'

SELECT
[status], ,enero, ,febrero,marzo
-- ,año

FROM OPENJSON ( @JSON )
with(  [status]            varchar(50) '$.status'
, mes nvarchar(max) as json  )
outer apply openjson   ( mes )
with ( enero          varchar(02) '$.enero'
,febrero        varchar(02) '$.febrero'
,marzo          varchar(02) '$.marzo'
)
-- with (ãno  int '$año')

**2 - lo que me sale**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco a quién pueda ayudarme.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta para la questión es:

```
declare @json varchar(max) = '{"status": "SUCCESS","VentaPajaros": {"codigoClient": 13216598,"composicionParcelas": [{"id": "07"},{"id": "08"}],"pago": {"fechaprimerpago": "09/12/2022","datosventa":{"valor": 304.63,"valorMinimo": 522.57},"cuota": {"valor": 174.07,"valorMinimo": 176.64}},"composicionAcuerdo": {"totalDeuda": 1490.62,"iof": 0,"notificacion": 0,"gestionProtesta": 0}}}'
```

select [status]
, codigoClient
, id
, fechaprimerpago
, datosventa_valor
, datosventa_valorMinimo
, cuota_valor
, cuota_valorMinimo
, totalDeuda
, iof
, notificacion
, gestionProtesta

from OPENJSON(@json)
with (
[status] varchar(50) '$.status'
,VentaPajaros nvarchar(max) as json
)
outer apply openjson(VentaPajaros)
with (
codigoClient varchar(50) '$.codigoClient'
,composicionParcelas nvarchar(max) as json
,pago nvarchar(max) as json
,composicionAcuerdo nvarchar(max) as json
)
outer apply openjson(composicionParcelas)
with (
id int '$.id'
)
outer apply openjson(pago)
with (
fechaprimerpago varchar(10) '$.fechaprimerpago'
,cuota nvarchar(max) as json
,datosventa nvarchar(max) as json
)

```
    outer apply openjson(datosventa)
    with (
            datosventa_valor decimal(16,2) '$.valor'
           ,datosventa_valorMinimo decimal(16,2) '$.valorMinimo'
          
          )  
    outer apply openjson(cuota)
    with (
            cuota_valor decimal(16,2) '$.valor'
           ,cuota_valorMinimo decimal(16,2) '$.valorMinimo'
          )  
                     
    outer apply openjson(composicionAcuerdo)
    with (
            totalDeuda decimal(16,2) '$.totalDeuda'
           ,iof decimal(16,2) '$.iof'
           ,notificacion  decimal(16,2) '$.notificacion'
           ,gestionProtesta  decimal(16,2) '$.gestionProtesta'
```